# Remove a water heater outlet, when removal spikes got broken during installation

Tags: electrical-panel, switch, walls, screws, smart-switch

I bought a "smart" controller for shower water heater. It used to be a normal on/off switch, and I bought a unit which connects to WiFi and I can control from an app.

I called an "installer" over to replace the switch, and during installation, it was necessary to remove the glass panel form the unit, in order to screw it to the wall.
The screws he used were too short, and now it's not fully attached to the wall.
During installation, the removal of the glass panel is done by pressing the "spikes" on the left edge of the panel with a screwdriver. Somehow, he managed to break one of the spikes, and the other spike is totally bent.

The result is as you see in the photo, and besides the fact it's not very aesthetic, I'm afraid that in the future, dust will infiltrate the unit and can reduced the life span of the unit.

I complained to the manufacturer that the spikes were faulty. He told me I can replace the unit with a new one at their expense.

Questions are:

1. Should I seek to remove (and replace) the unit, so once I have new one, I will install it myself with more care, and use longer screws to adhere it to the wall? How bad is it from product life-span perspective?
2. If I do want to remove it, how am I supposed to do it, other than breaking the glass panel in order unscrew it from the wall? I tried multiple times to insert a screwdriver under these plastic spikes, but the panel does not detach even a bit. Is there any tool I should use?

[image]

Comment: Have you asked the manufacturer that question?  They offered a new one, but maybe you need to call back and ask how you're supposed to remove the old one with defective spikes.

Comment: Why isn't this the installers problem?

Comment: Installer was a third party, not from manufacturer. and manufacturer didn't suggest any specific way to remove it while speaking to them.

Comment: It should still be on the installer (or whoever you hired/contracted who sent the installer) to fix the installation. Then the removal (up to and including breaking the unit) is on them. Also, did you _explicitly ask_ the mfgr how to remove this? The person you talked to may not have thought to volunteer the info, but might be quite happy to provide it if asked.

Answer (score 1):

The product life-span wouldn't be affected but the existing installation is pretty pathetic. You should wait until you get the new one from the manufacturer and read the instructions on how to remove/ install it. You could also look online using the model number of your product to get additional information. It looks like a small screwdriver would be all that's needed to remove the glass and frame but can't really tell for sure.Try forcing a screwdriver between the tab and the frame, not between the wall and the tab.

Comment: I have the instructions and they all rely on pushing the "spikes" with a scredriver to release the panel. you can see [in this video](https://youtu.be/JFaUA6CMLT0?t=44) how it's being removed. I tried a small screwdriver between the glass and the panel, but the glass it attached quite firmly. I guess that's one way to go, but this will eventually make it non-reversible. the glass isn't supposed to be removed but rather the glass with the panel, as you can see in the video. perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: Try forcing a screwdriver between the tab and the frame, not between the wall and the tab

Answer (score 0):

The clip holding the glass on the left-hand side are in a pretty bed shape and not working any more.

I see as only choice is to insert saw blade between the glass and the housing and cut off the plastic clips between the mirror in the housing.

With this action you obviously damage the product and you cannot use it anymore but it will allow you access to the screws behind holding the housing to the world.